# Using groupby on already grouped data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would like to achieve the result below in Python using Pandas.

[image]

I tried `groupby` and `sum` on the *id*  and *Group* columns using the below:

```py
df.groupby(['id','Group'])['Total'].sum()
```

I got the first two columns, but I'm not sure how to get the third column (*Overall_Total*).

How can I do it?

##### Initial data (before grouping)

| id | Group | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 |
| 1 | a | 2 |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 1 | b | 1 |
| 1 | b | 1 |
| 1 | c | 1 |
| 2 | e | 2 |
| 2 | a | 4 |
| 2 | e | 1 |
| 2 | a | 5 |
| 3 | c | 1 |
| 3 | e | 4 |
| 3 | a | 3 |
| 3 | e | 4 |
| 3 | a | 2 |
| 3 | h | 4 |

Comment: Can you share the initial dataframe, please ?

Comment: Hi, I have added the initial data ot teh question. thanks

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71491845/edit) (it covers input data as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` is your initial dataframe, please try this:

```
df_group = df.groupby(['id','group']).sum(['time']).rename(columns={'time':'Total'})
df_group['All_total'] = df_group.groupby(['id'])['Total'].transform('sum')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. The above snippet serves the purpose but the output data does not produce a grouped dataframe.

Comment: can you try the edited code posted above?

Comment: I hope you got what's required. Shall we delete the above comments?

Comment: Yes, please. I've marked your Answer. Thank you